# Mocha + Require Issue

Tags: requirejs, mocha.js

I'm trying to get Mocha (browser-version, not Node) running inside my (Require.js) environment, but I'm running in to a strange issue.

If I do:

```
<script src="require.js" data-main='mochaTestMain.js'></script>
```

and then do the following in mochaTestMain.js:

```
require(['someFile'], function() {
    describe('foo', function() {
        it('foo', function() {
            chai.expect(false).to.equal(true)
        });
    });
});
```

my "foo" spec results show up.  However if I put that exact same test inside `someFile.js` (inside a `define` statement), the test doesn't show up; it's like Mocha was never even aware that it existed.  If I add a `console.log` inside the `describe`, it shows up, but if I add one inside the `it` it doesn't.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to get Mocha to recognize tests defined in modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you call "mocha.run()" If it runs before the above tests, that may be one reason.

You can gain control over the timing of things by yanking the logic out of async threads into in-line flow:

contents of someTestFile.js:

```
;(function(){

    function setUpTests(){
        describe('foo', function() {
            it('foo', function() {
                chai.expect(false).to.equal(true)
            })
        })
    }

    // note, we are returning a test "constructor"
    define(function(){return setUpTests})

})();
```

contents of mochaTestMain.js:

```
;(function(){

    require(["someTestFile"], function(setUpTests){
        // defining of the test must come before
        setUpTests()
        // you run the test suite
        mocha.run()
    })

})();
```

Comment: I had `mocha.run()`, but I had a `require` where I should have had a `define` (or vice versa; I forget) that was messing everything up.  Thanks for the suggestions.